# Передача русскоязычных строковых данных от сервера к приложению

Tags: php, java, кодировка

У меня есть файл **URLConnecter.java** и файл **javatemp.php** на локальном сервере.

Задача:

> URLConnecter должен соединиться с сервером, получить строку и
>   сравнить ее со строкой "1abя"

Ниже привожу коды файлов (оба файла в формате UTF-8).

Проблема в том, что программа работает только, если сервер отправляет данные в формате cp1251.
Получается, что работать это будет только под windows.
Может есть способ решить данную задачу как-то более правильно?

Код файла **javatemp.php**:

```
echo iconv("UTF-8", "cp1251", "1abя");
//echo "1abя";
```

Код файла **URLConnecter.java**:

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class URLConnecter {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String urli = "http://java.loc/javatemp.php";
            String login = "Admin";
            String pass = "12345";
            String inputLine;
            URL myUrl = new URL(urli + "?login=" + login + "&pass=" + pass);
            URLConnection yc = myUrl.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        yc.getInputStream()));
            String result = "";
            String result_needle = "1abя";

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                result += inputLine;
            }
    /*
            char char1 = result.charAt(3);
            char char2 = result_needle.charAt(3);
            int int_char1 = (int) char1;
            System.out.println(int_char1);
            int int_char2 = (int) char2;
            System.out.println(int_char2); */
            //if (int_char1 == int_char2){
            //if (result == result_needle){
            if (result.equals(result_needle)){
                System.out.println("YES. EQUALS");
            } else {
                System.out.println("NO. NOT EQUALS");
            }
            in.close();
        }
    }
```

Компиляцию (перевод в URLConnecter.class) производил так:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin\javac.exe" -cp . -d . -encoding UTF-8 C:\URLConnecter.java
```

Запуск class-файла производил так:

```
java -cp . -DconsoleEncoding=UTF-8 URLConnecter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему не работает если сервер отправляет данные в UTF-8?

возможно изменение кодировки полученной строки вам может помочь.
Используйте эту функцию:

```
public static  String GetStringUTF8(byte[] data) {
        String outtxt = "";
        try
        {
            outtxt = new String(data, "UTF-8");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}
        return  outtxt;
    }
```

Применить её можно вот так:

```
result = GetStringUTF8(result.getBytes());
```

Так же проверьте настройки веб сервер, в какой кодировке он работает.

перед выводом в PHP можно явно указать кодирвку

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8', true);
```

а веб-серверу указать кодировку можно в файле .htaccess внеся следующую строку

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы получать от сервера ответ, можно посмотреть в какой кодировке отправляются данные, ну и читать в соответствующей кодировке.

```
String en = yc.getContentEncoding();
if (en == null) 
   en = "UTF-8";
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                      new InputStreamReader(
                        connection.getInputStream(),
                        en));
```

---

Вы можете посмотреть как читать и писать спомощью [`URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) в [тюториале по Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).